# Expected and actual column doesn't make sense in parsing error in R

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing

I have code that runs through a long list of URLS to make tables of air quality data. However, I keep getting a parsing error that I don't understand.

Here are my libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(chron)
library(lemon)
```

The code that generates the URLs, and then creates the tables looks like this:

```
i = 1
tempList <- list()


for(p in Pollutants){
  for(s in Stations){
    for(y in Years){


# Build URL
url_download <- paste("http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=",s,"&y=",y,"&p=",p,"&m=",mS,"&e=",mE,"&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1", sep = "")
print(url_download)

# Read in File
if(p == 124){
  MOE_download <- read_csv(file = url_download ,skip = 15 , na = c("9999", "-999"))
}else{
  MOE_download <- read_csv(file = url_download ,skip = 14 , na = c("9999", "-999"))
}
}
  }
}
```

However, I am getting an odd parsing error that I don't understand. It looks like this:

```
-- Column specification -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cols(
  `Chatham (13001)` = col_character()
)

Warning: 379 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual                                                                                                          file
  2  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1'
  3  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1'
  4  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1'
  5  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1'
  6  -- 1 columns 2 columns 'http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1'
```

It says it got 2 columns and expected 1, but that doesn't make sense to me because when I check the size of the dataframe, it looks like this:

```
dim(MOE_download_test)
[1] 384   1
```

If anyone could help me with this question I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Looking at http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/index.php?s=13001&y=2020&p=124&m=1&e=12&t=csv&submitter=Search&i=1 each row has a trailing comma.  The error is likely due to 27 header columns, but that trailing comma is being read as 28 columns per row.

Comment: Ah - good point! How can adjust for that in my loop - any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if there is a method to directly correct while reading into R.  Could check what other libraries support csv import to see if it can be handled.  Or read the file as text, strip any trailing commas and write back to file for inport.  Could also contact the source and see if they can correct the csv at creation.

Comment: Those are warnings but I think that does not impact the overall process for you. Do you still have all rows and all columns as expected?

Comment: @RonakShah yes, the rows and columns come out as expected. I have decided to just ignore the error in my code.